# avoid fadeout when moving mouse between two divs

Tags: jquery

When using `show` and `hide` moving the mouse between the two elements works fine. No flickering or such.

```
$(".blocka,.blockb").mouseenter(function(){
     $(".blockb").show();
});
$(".blocka,.blockb").mouseleave(function(){
     $(".blockb").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alewolf/07sramtq/1/

But, when using `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` the animation would always start between moving the mouse between the two elements.

```
$(".blocka,.blockb").mouseenter(function(){
     $(".blockb").fadeIn();
});
$(".blocka,.blockb").mouseleave(function(){
     $(".blockb").fadeOut();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alewolf/mLzejsvt/3/

I tried adding a timeout, but that didn't work.

The goal is that the green box only fades out if the mouse is being moved outside both elements.

Is there a simple way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a while of googling, and it is quite simple. (I had to go through quite a few iterations of my search terms).

Simply adding a `stop()` solves all of this perfectly.

```
$(".blocka,.blockb").mouseenter(function(){
     $(".blockb").stop().fadeIn();
});
$(".blocka,.blockb").mouseleave(function(){
     $(".blockb").stop().fadeOut();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alewolf/fts1qo09/13/

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `mouseenter` event listener is also added to `.blockb`. You need to stop `fadeIn` animation when mouse enters `blockb`.

Check out the snippet.

```js
$(".blocka").mouseenter(function(){
     $(".blockb").fadeIn();
});
$(".blocka,.blockb").mouseleave(function(){
     $(".blockb").fadeOut();
});

$(".blockb").mouseenter(function(){
     $(".blockb").stop();
});
```

```css
.blocka{width:150px;height:50px;background:red;}
.blockb{width:250px;height:50px;background:green; display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>
<div class="blocka"></div>
<div class="blockb"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Those both don't work properly because the green box only hides when the mouse leaves the wrapper `div`. That by itself is not a problem, but the wrapper `div` is much larger than the two boxes, and I need the green box to hide exactly when the mouse leaves and is outside of the two boxes. (When  the green box is open, moving the mouse to the white space above the green and to the right of the red box doesn't trigger hiding the green box.)

Comment: The flickering is happening because of change of action you are performing on the `.blockb`. When you just show `.blockb` on mouseenter on both divs, there is no flickering because show works instantly. While, fadeIn takes some time, which is why you see a flickering effect when the mouse leaves `blocka` and enters `blockb`.

I shall update my answer.

Comment: @alev I have updated the answer. Check it out. Please upvote it or accept it if it helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Ha. I found the solution almost at the same time as you. Well done ! Thanks,
but to be honest, I like my solution a little bit more, just because the the code is even simpler.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat. Accept either of the answers to help others seeking help. Have a nice day!